# Formatting the Django slacker-log-handler

Tags: django, python-3.x, logging, slack

I am using Django to log errors from my views.py file in my website. When using the slacker handler from: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slacker-log-handler, the formatter variable in the slack handler does not affect the message in slack.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here you first need to add slack-error in your logging handler.

Which is already shows here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slacker-log-handler

After that add below 2 lines in your code to send your "django.request" and "django.security" error to slack.

```
LOGGING['loggers']['django.request']['handlers'].append('slack-error')

LOGGING['loggers']['django.security']['handlers'].append('slack-error')
```

Also you can send custom error message. Check below code.

```
import logging
slack_logger = logging.getLogger("django.request")
```